# XML Path in ordering number SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I would like to get full range of date between two different temporary table for pivot table. The query is like this :

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @colswithNoNulls AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @tanggal_awal DATE
DECLARE @tanggal_akhir DATE
DECLARE @print NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @querycount AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

CREATE TABLE #datatable  
(
    product_id int,
    product_date date,
    product_ammount int
)

SET @tanggal_awal = convert(DATE,'02-01-2017')
SET @tanggal_akhir = convert(DATE,DATEADD(dd,-1,(DATEADD(mm,1,@tanggal_awal))))

INSERT INTO #datatable (product_id,product_date,product_ammount) 
VALUES (1, GETDATE(), 100), (1, GETDATE(), 900),
       (2, DATEADD(DD, -1, GETDATE()), 400),
       (3, DATEADD(DD, 4, GETDATE()), 300),
       (1, DATEADD(DD, 4, GETDATE()), 200),
       (2, DATEADD(DD, 2, GETDATE()), 700),
       (4, DATEADD(DD, -3, GETDATE()), 1000),
       (4, DATEADD(MM, 1, GETDATE()), 200)

;WITH CTE (datelist,maxdate) AS 
(
    SELECT 
        CONVERT(INT, (MIN(DATEPART(day, @tanggal_awal)))) datelist,   
        CONVERT(INT, MAX(DATEPART(day, product_date))) maxdate
    FROM 
        #datatable

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        CONVERT(INT, (DATEPART(day, datelist))), 
        CONVERT(INT, (DATEPART(day, @tanggal_akhir)))
    FROM 
        cte
    WHERE 
        datelist < maxdate
) 
SELECT c.datelist 
INTO #temp
FROM cte c
ORDER BY c.datelist
OPTION (maxrecursion 0)

SELECT * FROM #temp

SELECT 
    @cols = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(CONVERT(int, datelist)) 
                   FROM #temp
                   FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '') 

PRINT @cols
```

However, the result is not like i am expecting. Based on the print result, it shows something like this:

```
[1],[10],[11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18],[19],[2],[20],[21],[22],[23],[24],[25],[26],[27],[28],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9]
```

The result I want is something like this

```
 [1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18],[19],[20],[21],[22],[23],[24],[25],[26],[27],[28]
```

What should I do to solve this query? Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `DISTINCT` keyword and add an `ORDER BY` clause to the `SELECT` statement:

```
SELECT @cols =  STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(CONVERT(int, datelist)) 
                FROM #temp
                ORDER BY CONVERT(int, datelist)
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                ,1,1,''
                )
```

Comment: This have the potential to produce 2 numbers that are equal. This is why in my answer (that's almost identical to yours) I've added a group by clause.

Comment: so why i shouldn't use distinct in this problem ? your answer works like a charm :) . can you explain to me the mechanic when we distinct in xml parh ?

Comment: SQL Server won't allow a `DISTINCT` in this case. If you try, you will get _ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified._ error message. You need to guarantee that items in `datelist` don't repeat. Either add a `GROUP BY`, as suggested by @FarisFajar, or use `DISTINCT` when populating the `#temp` table: `SELECT DISTINCT c.datelist INTO #temp`

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it:

```
SELECT @cols =  STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(CONVERT(int, datelist)) 
                FROM #temp
                GROUP BY datelist
                ORDER BY CONVERT(int, datelist)
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                ,1,1,''
                )
```

I've changed the `DISTINCT` to `GROUP BY` so that I could use `CONVERT(int, datelist)` in the `ORDER BY` clause.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Getting TheOutput as
    [1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18],[19],[20],[21],[22],[23],[24],[25],[26],[27],[28]

      Begin TRAN

        DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
        DECLARE @colswithNoNulls AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
        DECLARE @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
        DECLARE @tanggal_awal DATE
        DECLARE @tanggal_akhir DATE
        DECLARE @print NVARCHAR(MAX)
        DECLARE @querycount AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

        CREATE TABLE #datatable  
        (
            product_id int,
            product_date date,
            product_ammount int
        )

        SET @tanggal_awal = convert(DATE,'02-01-2017')
        SET @tanggal_akhir = convert(DATE,DATEADD(dd,-1,(DATEADD(mm,1,@tanggal_awal))))

        INSERT INTO #datatable (product_id,product_date,product_ammount) VALUES 
                    (1,GETDATE(),100),
                    (1,GETDATE(),900),
                    (2,DATEADD(DD,-1,GETDATE()),400),
                    (3,DATEADD(DD,4,GETDATE()),300),
                    (1,DATEADD(DD,4,GETDATE()),200),
                    (2,DATEADD(DD,2,GETDATE()),700),
                    (4,DATEADD(DD,-3,GETDATE()),1000),
                    (4,DATEADD(MM,1,GETDATE()),200)

        ;WITH CTE (datelist,maxdate) AS 
        (
            SELECT CONVERT(INT,(MIN(DATEPART(day,@tanggal_awal)))) datelist, CONVERT(INT,MAX(DATEPART(day,product_date))) maxdate
            FROM #datatable
            UNION ALL
            SELECT CONVERT(INT,(DATEPART(day,datelist))), CONVERT(INT,(DATEPART(day,@tanggal_akhir)))
            FROM cte
            WHERE datelist < maxdate
        ) SELECT c.datelist 
            INTO #temp
            FROM cte c
            ORDER BY c.datelist
            OPTION (maxrecursion 0)

        --select * from #temp

        SELECT @cols =  STUFF((SELECT  ',' + QUOTENAME(CONVERT(nvarchar(20), datelist)) 
                        FROM #temp t1   
                         FOR XML PATH (''))
                  , 1, 1, '') from #temp t2


        SELECT @cols          


        PRINT @cols

        ROLLBACK TRAN
```

Comment: @FarisFajar Welcome